# Passing parameter to PayPal and getting it back

Tags: php, paypal, tracking

In order to sell a product I've created this "funnel"
Landing page -> payment page (external, at paypal) -> thank you page (internal)

All is working fine, but I've decided to add an affiliate program. the affiliate program adds a new parameter in the process - which is the tracking of the referrer.

So I've added a function on the landing page that gets the referrer id from the $_GET and sets it as a cookie, now I can identify him if he comes back or on the "thank you" page after payment - but - I don't have any way to associate it with his payment at PayPal.

So, due to the fact that the pay now button is actually a form I thought that there might be a way to add a hidden input field that will pass a parameter to paypal - but, the question remain - how do I get this parameter back so I can track the deal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PayPal's `custom` variable within your form's HTML code. PayPal will send it back when your payment is completed.

`<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="1234" />`

Alternatively, you could set the `notify_url` to give a query string containing your value.

`<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://example.com/ipn.php?aff=1234" />`

Comment: How does paypal sends them back?

Comment: You access the `custom` value the same way as you access the other values. Eg: `$_POST['custom']`. Notify_url can be accessed via `$_GET['aff']`

Comment: THanks Peter, You've helped a lot